# Select rows where, for the same value in column A, column B has a certain value in all rows

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to find rows where, for the same value in A, column B has a certain value in all rows.

For example, given table:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| mom | success |
| mom | success |
| dad | success |
| dad | failure |
| kid | failure |
| kid | failure |

Let's say I want all rows where column B is all 'failure' for the same value in column A. In this case, I would want:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| kid | failure |
| kid | failure |

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: oracle sql. Tried to find a tag for it, but didn't see one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.a = t.a and t2.b <> 'failure'
                 );
```